# How can you add a view to a specific area in a Drupal page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

hope someone can help me.  I created my own collapse panel on the following page:

http://designerandpublisher.com/drupal-testing/?q=donald-case-page

It's at the bottom of the above page where the blue box is and the word empty... is.

Also please note on the above page the Donald Stories and the links on the right sidebar.  That is a view I created and any time you write a new page and select the correct tag, the new page's link will populate in that Donald Stories section.

But here's what I really want to happen - I want that Donald Stories view to appear where the word "empty..." is so that it's inside of that collapse panel (for demo purposes, the collapse panel is permanently open to show what's inside of it).

I know I could set up a new region for the "content" portion of the theme, but if I do, and then add Donald Stories block to that region, it will just show up in the page's body at the bottom but won't be where the word "empty..." is.  How would I specifically tell that new region to appear where "empty..." is, since I created that collapse panel myself and it's not another view or block?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to showcase view in specific page?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I want the Donald Stories "view" to appear where the word "empty..." is.  You can see it on the link I added to my original post.  Thanks.

Comment: If the "empty" text is in a panel this might help: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26533/adding-a-view-to-a-panel. If it's in a node or block, this will help: https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view

Comment: I added the insert views module to my site.  the machine name of the view i'm trying to display is donald_stories so i added [view:donald_stories] to body of page and it doesn't work. it also said you have to go to filters to set up the insert view but i cannot find that in my site. can you help? you can see what i did at URL list in 1st post

Comment: Never mind I got it working.  The Insert View module / filter works great and now I can add a view right into the body of my page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can display block/view in specific page following below steps.

1) Go to block list & click '**configure**'

2) **REGION SETTINGS** - Choose the region that where you want to display block.

3) **Visibility settings** - **Show block on specific pages** -> select '**Only the listed pages**' and enter page list below textarea.

**[Know more](http://www.freebiezz.com/blog/create-block-drupal-7)**

Note: You can place block/view only in theme regions. So you should have region to display block/view. You cannot place block anywhere in the page.